# How to use TypeScript definition file without strong name in moduleless environment

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

I'm using Visual Studio 2013/TypeScript 1.8.5/NPM/Typings.

I want to compile TypeScript to ES5 code with some React JSX, and more importantly, with no modules.

Some definition files typings is fetching me have only an string named module. By "string named", I mean like this:

```
declare module "redux-devtools" {}
```

When others have this:

```
declare namespace Redux {}
declare module "redux" {}
```

When there is what i call a "strong name", I can use those definitions directly in my code.

```
var foobar = Redux;
```

But when there is only a string named module, I don't know how to use them. For what I understand, I have to use an import statement, but when I do I get a "cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided", and again, I do not want modules in my target code.

```
import { createDevTools } from 'redux-devtools';
const DevTools = createDevTools(/**/);
```

Is there a particular way to do this? Or is it the definition files, like redux-devtools, which are wrong in the first place?

EDIT:

If I compile TypeScript to ES6, I no longer get the "cannot compile modules..." message when I import external modules. TypeScript generates statements like this instead:

```
const redux_devtools_1 = require('redux-devtools');
```

I find it surprising since 'require()' is not part of ES6, which means I would have to use es6-shim + RequireJS for this solution to work?

Also, I do have a general '_references.ts' file, like this:

```
 /// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ["triple-slash reference"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) `/// <reference path="...">` instead of the `import` statements to pull in your library definitions.

This lets TypeScript know about those types so it will compile, but won't try to generate any modules.

It's then up to you to make sure that those library implementations are available in your runtime environment.